# Classic chain rule for Ito diffusion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose we have a simple Ito diffusion model

$$dX(t)=\mu dt + \sigma dW(t)$$

and function which is at least twice differentiable $y=k(x)$

then by Ito's Lemma we have 
$$
{\mathrm{d} k(X(t))} = \left(\frac{\partial k(X(t))}{\partial t} + \mu \frac{\partial k(X(t))}{\partial x} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 k(X(t))}{\partial x^2}\right)dt + \sigma \frac{\partial k(X(t))}{\partial x} dW(t)
$$

However, suppose we are in a setting where the function $k(x)$ is unknown and we want to separate it somehow. Is the following "classical chain rule" allowed?

$$
\frac{\partial k(X(t))}{\partial t} =  \frac{\partial k(x)}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial k(X(t))}{\partial t} 
$$

I am interested on how we approach situations where we know $X(t)$ and we know the integrated process of the transformed $X(t)$ by a function i.e.: $k(x)$ - then is it possible to solve or approximate the function...?

Comment: Say you know the exact solution of the SDE of $k(X(t))$ (i.e. with coefficient in terms of known functions), then you can compare it with the coefficient of the above one derived from Ito's lemma, which allow you to solve a system of pde.

Comment: @BGM Very interesting but in my scenario you only observe the mean signal of the fully integrated solution in $x$ of $k(X(t))$; hence, it is just a simple function of time $t$ say $H(t)$